# Strange MVC4 Authentication Behavior - User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an **Internet Application** from the available MVC4 templates. This template generates an  **AccountController** which I am trying to use. The issue is that even after the **WebSecurity.Login()** returning true, the **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** still returns false, which I don't understand why. First I thought it was late initialization of the **InitializeSimpleMembership** attribute over the AccountController and so, I moved that part to Application_Start() routine of the Global.ascx.cs, but it didn't make any difference. Here is the relevant code that I am using.

**Account Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)) {

        //Why this should ever return false?
        bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; 

        //returns false, even when I log in "Admin" role !
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) { 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" });
        }
        ....
}
```

**Global.ascx.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        ...
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);

     }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer() {
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

The msdn documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) states that if the user is logged in, it returns true. So, in the above **AccountController** code, the **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** should always be returning True, but that's not happenning. Its returning false. Any ideas why ?

**Edit**

My primary issue is to get roles for a given user after he has authenticated successfully, i.e. after the **WebSecurity.Login()** returns true.

**Edit 2**

Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") returns false even when I log in "Admin" role

User.IsInRole("Admin") returns false even when log in "Admin" role. This is already mentioned in the code posted
in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` won't return true on your login request until the next request when the Forms Auth cookie is properly set with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

`The SetAuthCookie method adds a forms-authentication ticket to either the cookies collection or the URL if CookiesSupported is false. The forms-authentication ticket supplies forms-authentication information to the next request made by the browser. With forms authentication, you can use the SetAuthCookie method when you want to authenticate a user but still retain control of the navigation with redirects.`

If you want to see if the login succeeded, use the return value from `WebSecurity.Login`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx

To check the users role, use Roles.IsUserInRole() then. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My primary issue was to check whether the user belongs to "Admin" role or some other role. What should then be used to know the roles after WebSecurity.Login() returns true ?

Comment: You can use WebSecurity.RequireRoles. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.requireroles(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: I don't think this would help me either. I have 2 mvc layout pages, one for ordinary User (role="user") and other for Admins (role="admin"). When the any user logs into successfully, I have to determine whether the user belongs to "admin" or "user" role and then based on that, Redirect to their respective page. The above WebSecurity.RequireRoles() does not fit in here, because it sets the 401 (Unauthorized) status code which I don't want.

Comment: Use Roles.IsUserInRole() then. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please see my Edit 2.